# PHP fastCGI won't stop, trying to start PHP fpm

Tags: centos, php, fastcgi

I installed php-fpm and tried to start it. Got the following error:

```
ERROR: unable to bind listening socket for address '127.0.0.1:9000': Address already in use (98)
```

So it would appear php-fastcgi is using the address:

```
[root@singularity ~]# netstat -tulnp | grep ":9000"
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9000              0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      14595/php-cgi
```

But I can't stop php-fastcgi service:

```
[brad@singularity ~]$ sudo /etc/init.d/php-fastcgi stop
Stopping php-cgi:                                          [FAILED]
```

Is this normal? Any ideas why? Or where I could look for errors?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try killing the service manually

```
ps aux | grep php
```

find the PID number, and kill that pid

```
kill [PID NUMBER]
```

Then try to start again

```
sudo /etc/init.d/php-fastcgi start
```

this work ?

Comment: Awesome. I did something very similar to this, but apparently there were a lot of processes (I had to kill about 5). Is that normal for a service like this?

Comment: i think yes the fastcgi can spawn many process depends on the configuration PHP_FCGI_CHILDREN